# Send data to Flask server using websockets

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, flask, websocket

I have a complicated project (not my code...) where a Flask servers launches computations using SCOOP -- that is, in another thread.

I'd like to know how I can send intermediary data from my SCOOP thread to display it on my Flask web page. I am not afraid of a little Javascript.

[Python websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.org) seems like the way to go, but I'm unsure how to use it.

Let's say I will use Javascript this way in my Flask web page to fetch my data (example from Websockets' doc) :

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678/");
var messages = document.createElement('ul');
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Now, all my data is encapsulated in an object (`Calibration2` -- again, not my code!). So, the following example (still from Websockets' doc) does not suit me:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
        yield from websocket.send(now)
        yield from asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)

start_server = websockets.serve(time, '127.0.0.1', 5678)
```

Because I want the handler coroutine to be part of my `Calibration2` class, and call it whenever `Calibration2` wants to. But according to Websockets, the coroutine has to have this prototype, with `websocket` and `path`. But how can I access `Calibration2`'s insides from such a function?

I'm pretty sure my issue is mostly a misunderstanding of Python scopes. I'm not a pro (yet!). So, if you can point me in some direction, I'd be glad, thanks!

Comment: You could try `socket.io` on the client and `flask-socketio` on the server.

Comment: It sounds good, but I still don't understand how I can run my computations and the Flask server on the same thread. Once I launch `socketio.run(app)`, the execution is stopped. Where can I put my `computing_object.do_stuff()` ?

Comment: you could ask a separate question about how to structure flask-socketio -based web-applications.